# FTP Connection issue

Tags: ftp, windows-sbs-2008

I am trying to access a FTP server with Anonymous Access, this worked until recently and now will not allow Anonymous to login, although it prompts for a username and password so the service is still running.

I have no idea where this FTP server is on this network, we have two IIS servers one SBS 2008 server which does not have FTP installed and another IIS with ver6 and ver7 which also does not seem to have FTP enabled, however when I do a nslookup of the IP address I connect too it points to the SBS2008 server, but the FTP server is disabled and when I try to enable it I get a prompt along the lines of "this ip already exsists on this network, to enable please disable the other".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you had another server take over the IP. I'm guessing you didn't want this to happen, so you'll need to track down the physical location of the server with the IP in question by tracing it to it's network endpoint port and dealing with it at that point.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, static IPs for you servers would be ideal.  You are going to have involve your network infrastructure team to track down the switchport your FTP server is plugged into, like John said there's an IP conflict, so grab the MAC address of your server and take it to them.

Comment: Ok I've found it, it was on the SBS2008 server :/ .. I've stopped and started the service and reset the password, but it still prompts for a username and password, I've ticked allow anon connections and allow only anon connections, and as above the user account has been reset.

Comment: Also when I try to login using the anon account it prompts me for an email address.

Comment: Ok, reset everything following https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/26a80508-791c-42c2-bb2e-1427d4ddf8c2.mspx?mfr=true    everything is working again.